# Swift Object Mapper passing a different date

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I'm using ObjectMapper to get json into objects, but each time the date is set as 1970-01-01. I can't see what my issue is since I though DateTransform would be able to handle the format.

Here's the class:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class example :Mappable
{
    var ExampleDate: Date?

    required init?(map: Map){
    }

    //Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map){
        ExampleDate          <- (map["ReviewDate"], DateTransform())
    }

}
```

This is how one of the dates looks:

ExampleDate = "2018-07-05T12:41:52.087+00:00"

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `DateFormatterTransform` instead:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class example :Mappable
{
    var ExampleDate: Date?

    required init?(map: Map){
    }

    //Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map){
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

        ExampleDate <- (map["ReviewDate"], DateFormatterTransform(dateFormatter: dateFormatter))
    }
}
```

And as a general observation try do avoid using a capital first letter for your variable names. It's the recommended way so you can easily distinguish them from types. So use `exampleDate` instead of `ExampleDate`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: it changes the date value as "String" , not Date() anymore.